# Calculation for background characteristic of data sets that were imputed by mice and matched by MatchThem

Tags: missing-data, propensity-scores, mice

I have performed multiple imputation in mice and created a dataset of 100 imputed data sets and then used MatchThem to perform propensity score matching.
I can assess the balance of matched data sets with the bal.tab function in the cobalt package, but I would also like to know the average background characteristics of the population after matching (for example, mean age of matched subjects). Please let me know if there are any useful functions or packages to compute the average background information of the multiple imputed data sets that were created mice and matched by MatchThem.

Answer (score 1):

You can view means and standard deviations within each imputed dataset by requesting balance on all the imputed datasets and requesting the means be displayed. The code below does this:

```r
bal.tab(m.out, which.imp = .all, disp = c("means", "sds"))
```

If you want a single number for each variable that describes the distribution of each covariate across all imputed datasets, there is none. There is no single distribution of `age` in the matched datasets; there are $M$ matched datasets and a different distribution of each covariate within each one. What value would you like to compute and display? If you have a suggestion feel free to submit an [issue](https://github.com/ngreifer/cobalt/issues) and I will look into implementing it. As far as I know, there are no standards for reporting this kind of value.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.
I would like to get a single number for each variable that describes the distribution of each covariate across all imputed data sets. This is because I want to present the background characteristics of the final analyzed population in a single table.
For example, if there are 100 imputed data sets, I would like to get 100 mean values for each variable calculated from the matched data sets, and then show a single mean value calculated from those mean values.
I understand that there is no such functionality. Thank you.